# Как получить доступ к полям, которые находятся в отдельной разметке?

Tags: android, kotlin

```
class ExploreActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
lateinit var binding: ActivityExploreBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityExploreBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    val name = intent.getStringExtra("name")
    val email = intent.getStringExtra("email")
    val password = intent.getStringExtra("password")
}
```

}**Нужно полученные данные из поля регистрации засунуть в TextView, которые находятся в отдельной разметки header для drawerNavigationView. Я не использую фрагменты. Код разметки header ниже**

````
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:background="@drawable/drawer_menu_header"
    android:visibility="visible">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView3"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.088"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/avatar" />
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:letterSpacing="0.3"
        android:text="Kirill"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.398"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:letterSpacing="0.3"
        android:text="Zhilnikov"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/name"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/name"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/name" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:text="Email:"
        android:textColor="#AFABAB"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/cardView3"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/cardView3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cardView3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
        android:text="Password:"
        android:textColor="#AFABAB"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/cardView3"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/cardView3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cardView3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="96dp"
        android:text="Kirill.Zhilnikov37@mail.ru"
        android:textColor="#AFABAB"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.559"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="116dp"
        android:text="204030748qwe"
        android:textColor="#AFABAB"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>```
````

Comment: я начинающий, поэтому может мой ответ будет не верным. Если вам нужно временное отображение текста в поле из другого поля - то берете значение поля, переводите его в переменную, эту переменную присваиваете другому полю - public lateinit var peremen: EditText //  peremen = binding.pole1 // pole2.text = peremen (или pole2.setText(peremen )   Если надо приводите к виду стринг или интегер.

Comment: дело в том, что это 2 разных разметки, поэтому для начала разметку с header нужно надуть, а как это сделать, непонятно)

Comment: а если переменные сделать public ? тогда они будут видны во всём проекте.

Comment: Покажите фрагмент разметки активити (activity_explore.xml), как вы в нее встраиваете drawerNavigationView? С помощью тега include? Добавьте эту информацию в ваш вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы установить значение в TextView, сначала получим эту TextView по идентификатору:

```kotlin
val emailView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.email)
```

Далее, заполним нужным значением:

```kotlin
emailView.setText(email)
```

Чтобы то же самое сделать с помощью [View Binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding), необходимо указать идентификатор для разметки, которую вы встраиваете в разметку активити:

```xml
<include
    android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    layout="@layout/navigation_drawer_layout" />
```

Тогда достатью вью и записать в нее значение можно следующим образом:

```kotlin
binding.navigationDrawer.email.setText(email)
```